# Leaky bucket vs token buckets - rate limiter

Tags: rate-limiting

So reading about Leaky bucket algorithm I'm trying to understand if the implementation differs between implementors or I'm missing something.

Reading about it, it says leaky bucket is used to keep a constant pace of retrieval (e.g 2 requests/second). So if the configuration is bucket size of 40 and 2 qps, any requests that will be reached when the bucket is full (larger than 40) will be throttled.

But, what happens to requests when the bucket is not full ? are they actually added to a queue and wait? (that doesn't make much sense I suppose cause it will affect latency).
If they don't actually wait, then the pace of handling requests is not constant on 2 qps, but allow bursts up to 40.
However, in this case, what is the difference between leaky bucket and token bucket other than the fact one removes tokens and one adds tokens ? it looks like both allow bursts and both will try smooth handling requests after bursts to the QPS defined.